# texture is missing when I turn on the alpha mode

Tags: transparency

When I turn on the alpha transparency it doesn't show my texture anymore since I installed the 2.93.5 version.
Please if you have any solution

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello, could you please give more details? for example show your node setup

Comment: Sure ! result in the viewport : https://imgur.com/Nk48dq2         Setup : https://imgur.com/O1jD6ok

Comment: maybe first plug the Alpha output of the Image Texture into the Alpha input of the Principled BSDF?